# Compojure-api: Request coercion for a map supplied via multipart-params

Tags: clojure, compojure, compojure-api

I am trying to integrate compojure-api (version 1.1.12) into an existing compojure-based application.  While most things work, I am having an issue with request coercions on an existing REST call whose usage would be difficult to change at this point.

- It's a POST
- It expects parameters via multipart/form-data
- Most parameters are optional.
- Most parameters are simple: string or array of string.
- One optional parameter is expected to be a JSON-encoded map.

I define the route like this:

```
(POST "/endpoint" request
    :multipart-params 
        [required-strings :- (describe [s/Str] "Required, an array of strings"),
         {optional-string :- (describe s/Str "An optional string") ""},
         {others :- {s/Keyword s/Any} {}}]
    ...)
```

This works, unless I try to pass `other-parameters` in a request.  For example, via curl:

```
curl -F "required-strings=[\"Hello\"]" -F "others={\"a\":1.0}" ...
```

This results in an invalid request (i.e. status 400) error with the content:

```
{"errors":{"others":"(not (map? a-clojure.lang.PersistentVector))"}}
```

I'm using ring-default's `site-defaults`, and I haven't modified the default coercions for the compojure api.  I've traced the error to `compojure.api.coerce/coerce`.  I can see the value that the coercer is working on, and it looks like:

```
{:required-strings "[\"Hello\"]"
 :others "{\"a\":1.0}"}
```

On line 59 of coerce.clj, `(coerce value)` returns an error (per `schema.utils/error?`).

So, is it not possible to coerce a JSON-encoded multipart parameter to a Clojure map? I can define the parameter to be a string instead of a map, and do the parsing myself, but this defeats the purpose of using compojure-api and ring-swagger.

Answer (score 1):

The coercer for `others` expects a clojure map not a string. To make it work you have to options.

First option: add [wrap-json-params](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json/blob/92db7781fb2bcbf1cfdbef6e5d56fdd46e93109e/src/ring/middleware/json.clj#L78) middleware and do `application/json` request instead of `multipart/form-data`:

```
curl ... -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d $'{
  "required-strings": ["Hello"],
  "others": {"a": 1.0}
}'
```

Second option: add [wrap-nested-params](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/f39f06c769ec5d9ef08c986d12a169d623c75293/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/nested_params.clj#L68) middleware and `multipart/form-data` request using nested param names:

```
curl ... -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
     -F "required-strings[]=Hello" \
     -F "others[a]=1.0"
```